# return and print in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, return

how can I return the output of the function print () in python? I have the following function

```
def read_image(raw_image_path):
    raw_image_path = get_one_track()
    with open (raw_image_path) as raw_image_file:
        content = raw_image_file.readlines()
        for content in itertools.islice(content,1,len(content)):
            image_id = content.split()[0]   
            driver_id = content.split()[2]
            camera_spec = content.split()[1] + content.split()[2]
            image_spec = [image_id,driver_id,camera_spec]

            image_folder_file = read_img_folders_file()[0]
            cam_spec=read_img_folders_file()[1]
            nb = read_img_folders_file()[2]
            image_path=''
            for i in range(nb-1):
            if cam_spec[i]== image_spec[2]:
                image_path=image_folder_file[i]+'/'

            raw_image= image_path+str(image_id).zfill(10)+'.png' 
            #print (raw_image)
            return (raw image)
```

The problem is that when I use print (raw_image) I become all the images I need like

```
/home/stereo_front_left/0000001756.png
/home/stereo_front_left/0000001757.png
/home/stereo_front_left/0000001758.png
```

but when I try the get them outside the function I become just the first one. What can I do?

Comment: yes `print()` terminates the function, use `yield raw_image` and then when you execute the function use `print(list(read_image(raw_image_path)))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I think you meant: "**`return`** terminates the function."

Comment: @Chris_Rands "print terminates the function"? since when?

Comment: @khelwood Matthias indeed, I meant `return` of course, apologies for any confusion caused

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the raw_image outside the loop, you would need to store them in a list or somewhere and then write "return all_raw_images".

```
    all_raw_images = []
    for content in itertools.islice(content,1,len(content)):
            image_id = content.split()[0]   
            driver_id = content.split()[2]
            camera_spec = content.split()[1] + content.split()[2]
            image_spec = [image_id,driver_id,camera_spec]

            image_folder_file = read_img_folders_file()[0]
            cam_spec=read_img_folders_file()[1]
            nb = read_img_folders_file()[2]
            image_path=''
            for i in range(nb-1):
                if cam_spec[i]== image_spec[2]:
                    image_path=image_folder_file[i]+'/'

            raw_image= image_path+str(image_id).zfill(10)+'.png' 
            all_raw_images.append(raw_image)

    return (all_raw_images)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to make print() return.

It is a function, not a method, so it automatically returns.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question. :)